# Reading characters from an unknown character encoding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, encoding, asp.net-2.0

I have a string that came from an old database of unknown character encoding.  I am having trouble encoding/filtering the string to show the correct text.

What the data looks like in the database: MarronniÃ¨re Ã  quatre pans

What we need the string to show up as: Marronnière à quatre pans

Specifically, I am having trouble parsing the string so I can display the character à  (`&#224;`)

This is an asp.Net 2.0 site written in VB using a Sql Server 2005 Database.  Not sure if it matters, but data comes from a column with this collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I've tried encoding the string to various encodings in the code to no avail.  I've also passed the string (encoded different ways) into a byte array to find a unique byte pattern for the bad characters without success.

Any ideas or leads would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the collation in the SQL Server database doesn't match the character encoding that was actually used :( It's a fairly common mistake for careless developers.

That's why the SQL Server administration tools are showing weird characters rather than the strings that you are expecting.

Possibly it is UTF-8? In UTF-8 `Ã` is represented by the bytes `0xC3 0xA8`, which would be interpreted under the Windows code page Latin-1 as `Ã¨`. I know nothing about SQL Server collations, but it seems likely that SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS is similar to Windows "Latin-1".

You either need to

- fix up the encoding when reading from the database. Ugly and confusing for the next poor victim who has to deal with this database and code.
- or, better, correct the data in the database so that it matches the collation. You might like to change the collation to UTF-8 or UTF-16: you will also need to change the data though.